# Does a rectangle NEED a texture to be drawn?

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I want to draw some rectangles to create boundaries for my player. When i went to draw them i noticed that it needed a texture. This confused me and made me wonder if it needs a texture.

Comment: Please add your code that creates and draws the rectangles. You can draw triangles with just colors, if you have a shader that supports it.

Comment: `public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(mapBounderyTexture, new Vector2(100, 100), Color.Black); 
        }`

Answer (score 1):

Actually yes, you need a texture to draw a rectangle. 
Which sounds odd if you just want to create boundaries around an object. The solution for this is to create a "1-pixel-texture" that you draw accordingly:

```
public Texture2D pixel;
protected override void Initialize()
{
    ...
    pixel = new Texture2D(GraphicsDevice, 1, 1);
    pixel.SetData(new[] { Color.White }); //
    ...
}

protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    ...
    int bw = 2; // Border width
    spriteBatch.Draw(pixel, new Rectangle(Player.PlayerPositionRectangle.Left, Player.PlayerPositionRectangle.Top, bw, Player.PlayerPositionRectangle.Height), Color.Black); // Left
    spriteBatch.Draw(pixel, new Rectangle(Player.PlayerPositionRectangle.Right, Player.PlayerPositionRectangle.Top, bw, Player.PlayerPositionRectangle.Height), Color.Black); // Right
    spriteBatch.Draw(pixel, new Rectangle(Player.PlayerPositionRectangle.Left, Player.PlayerPositionRectangle.Top, Player.PlayerPositionRectangle.Width, bw), Color.Black); // Top
    spriteBatch.Draw(pixel, new Rectangle(Player.PlayerPositionRectangle.Left, Player.PlayerPositionRectangle.Bottom, Player.PlayerPositionRectangle.Width, bw), Color.Black); // Bottom
    ...
}
```

Notice:
In my case 'PlayerPositionRectangle' is just the players position including the size of the player texture. You can add offsets for interaction range, collision or what ever you want:

```
Rectangle(X, Y, spriteWidth, spriteHeight);
```